# Office Word Add In - Converting file to Base64 and then Inserting It

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

On Button click I am wanting to convert a stored file on the server to Base64 and store that as a string. Then insert that file into the current open document via the Office Word Addin API "insertFileFromBase64" using the stored base64 string.

I have low level knowledge of JS and have spent a lot of time researching how to do this but just can't figure it out myself, any help would be appreciated thanks.

Here is my code:

```
 export async function insertFile() {
    await Word.run(async (context) => {

    // Convert file to base64 string
       const fileToBase64 = (filename, filepath) => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          var file = new File([filename], filepath);
          var reader = new FileReader();
          // Read file content on file loaded event
          reader.onload = function(event) {
            resolve(event.target.result);
          };
          
          // Convert data to base64 
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
      };

      // Convert file to base64
      let file = fileToBase64("test.docx", "./test.docx");

      // At current mouse selection in document insert file from base64 string
      let rangeBase64 = context.document.getSelection();
      rangeBase64.insertFileFromBase64(file, Word.InsertLocation.end);

     await context.sync();
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          console.log("Error: " + error);
          if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
              console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
          }
      });
}
```

Comment: hi, do you want to get the file base64 at client side or server side? I see you already have code listed above to get the file at client side, right? If you want to get it at serer side, then you need to confirm what's the server side code you are using. For example, if server side code is c++, just search in google and you will get how to get a file base64 in c++. Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you find a way to do this ?

Comment: @Furya I ended up storing all my docx files locally and using a cronjob to run a python script to convert them to base64. Then I called the word insertFileFromBase64 API.